Namespacing Model Files in Typescript
I'm trying to namespace the interfaces contained in my types/ directory. To do this, I'm using modules containing nothing but Typescript structures (interface, type). When I try to import these modules, I get an error
The requested module '../types/Model' does not provide an export named 'default'

The error goes away when I add something like const foo = '' to the module, so I'm assuming the error has something to do with there not being anything to transpile to JS in the module.
Is there a different way I should be namespacing collections of interfaces like this?
For more detail, my repository is structured like so
src/
 - handlers/
  + SomeFile.ts
 - includes/
 - types/
  - handlers/
   + SomeFileModel.ts
  - includes/

Where each XModel.ts contains types relevant to its corresponding X.ts in src/
The models are structured
module SomeFileModel {
  export interface Foo {
    x: string,
    y: string
  }
}

export default SomeFileModel

Then the types are used like
import SomeFileModel from 'types/handlers/SomeFileModel'
const x: SomeFileModel.Foo = {
  x: 'f',
  y: 'g'
}


Share specifics.

@ChukwujiobiCanon, updated with specifics
